# array to string conversion in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to fetch some data from table in laravel 5.0 like so

```
public function index()
    {
        $data = DB::table('modules')->get();

        return view("BaseView.home")->with('data',$data);
    }
```

this is my view

```
 @foreach($data as $modules)
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            {{ $modules->module_name }}<i class="plusMinus fa fa-plus-square plusMinusSpacing" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            {!! $moduleCategories = DB::table('module_categories')->where('modules_id','=',$modules->id)->get() !!}
            @foreach($moduleCategories as $category)
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ $category->categories_name }}</a>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </li>
    @endforeach
```

$module->id is obtained from another query result. Now when I try to run this I am getting `Array to string conversion`. Can someone point out the mistake. The expected output is > 1 in the sense there can be multiple categories names matching that condition.

Comment: This seems to be `$category->categories_name` an array so you need to iterate over it

Comment: try `@foreach($moduleCategories->categories_name as $category)` and in the href link `$category->name` or however you named the field

Comment: Use `whereIn` for array

Comment: @Carlos the problem is in the query not in the `foreach`

Comment: @Thamilan I am getting this error when I do this `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in `

Comment: is the variable `$module` an array?

Comment: I have updated the full code have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to put php logic inside an echo `{{ ... }}`. You are trying to echo out a collection or an array of data, hence the error you are getting, `Array to string conversion`. The proper way to do this is to do the logic in the controller. But for a quick fix, replace:

```
{!! $moduleCategories = DB::table('module_categories')->where('modules_id','=',$modules->id)->get() !!}
```

to

```
<php $moduleCategories = DB::table('module_categories')->where('modules_id','=',$modules->id)->get(); ?>
```

Never use `{{ ... }}` or `{!! ... !!}` to put logic, those are to echo out a string.

==EDIT==

I suggest to use laravels eloquent relationship methods, this will simplify the code, and seperate the logic from the view.

Note: Expecting if you are using laravel naming convention.

On your `Modules` model, add a relationship to `ModuleCategory` like so:

```
public function module_categories()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ModuleCategory');
}
```

On your controller, on the index method replace :

```
$data = DB::table('modules')->get();
```

with

```
$data = Modules::get();
```

and finally on the view, change it like so:

```
@foreach($data as $modules)
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        {{ $modules->module_name }}<i class="plusMinus fa fa-plus-square plusMinusSpacing" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
        @foreach($modules->module_categories as $category)
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ $category->categories_name }}</a>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I get it. But I think I need to escape the `>` because it is not closing properly.

Comment: what part are you referring `>` to?

Comment: `->` in the query. It is outputting the whole thing after `->`

Comment: i suggest you research a little over Laravels eloquent relationship https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many, i will update my answer with a quick example

Comment: Why have you removed the second query? and what does this `$modules->module_categories as $category` do?

Comment: `$modules->module_categories` is pretty much executing the second query you have. When we added the method `module_categories()` in your `Modules` model, we are saying, everytime i call `module_categories` on a `Modules` object, i want you to bring all of its `module_categories` of that `module`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139519/discussion-between-this-believer-and-carlos).

Comment: "You are trying to echo out a collection or an array of data, hence the error you are getting..."
Really? In my case, when the object is a collection, it doesn't cause this error. (If it's an array, this results in an array as you explain)

Comment: I mean... (If it's an array, this results in an ERROR as you explain)

Answer (score 0):

As I commented on Carlos's solution, here is how I solved the same error...

```
//Controller
$users  = User::where('blah', 'blah')->get();
return view('index', [
   'users'  => $users,
]);


//View
<script type="text/javascript">
  angular.module("app").factory("DataService", function() {
    return {
      users: {!! $users !!},
    };
 });
</script>
```

As discussed above, this will result in the `Array to string conversion` error, since `$users` is an array.

However, this error won't happen if `$users` is a `collection'

I.e.

```
//Controller
$users  = User::all();
return view('index', [
   'users'  => $users,
]);
//This is ok
```

Or,

```
//Controller
$users  = collect([]);
return view('index', [
   'users'  => $users,
]);
//This is fine too
```